# Software for Feasibility Problems

Tags: constrained-optimization, software, software-recommendation

I face a feasibility problem of type

$$ c_i(\boldsymbol x) \leq 0, i = 1, \dots, \mathcal{I} \\ c_e(\boldsymbol x) = 0, e = 1, \dots, \mathcal{E} $$

where $\mathcal{I}  + \mathcal{E}  \gg \text{dim}(\boldsymbol x) \sim \mathcal{O} (10^1) $.

Currently, I solve this with [Ipopt](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/) but since it takes quite some time (many iterations reqiuired) I thought about looking for some special feasible point solvers.

The "largest" (3) collection of feasible point solvers I could find online are mentioned in section 5.3 of [this paper](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/opt/preprints/prep2010/amna_opap_10_03.pdf).
Unfortunately, there seems to be no implementation of the therein developed algorithm (`EFNES`) online.
The [`FILTRANE`](https://www.galahad.rl.ac.uk/doc/filtrane.pdf) framework of the [Galahad package](https://github.com/ralna/GALAHAD) might be quite effective but has a nasty Fortran API which looks even for the example problem quite difficult.

EDIT: The link in the original `TRESNEI` paper is dead, but I found [this working one](https://flore.unifi.it/handle/2158/1271224).

Any suggestions besides the usual suspects from nonlinear optimization, ideally free to use within academia?

Comment: Can you tell us how many variables and constraints you have? How is IPOPT slow (is one iteration slow, or does it need many iterations)?

Comment: The latter is the case.

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit by stating what a feasibility problem is? Do you have one short sample solution that illustrates what is going on?

Comment: I came across this: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/alt_proj.pdf and it may be useful for you.

Comment: If you can model your problem in AMPL, give filterSQP a try (online): https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/nco:filter/AMPL.html

Comment: Are the constraints linear?  A detailed example would likely encourage more complete responses.

Comment: The inequality constraints are of form $c_i(\boldsymbol x) = \left \vert 1 + \prod_{j=1}^N \frac{c_j + d_ji}{x_j + f(x_j)i} \right \vert$

Answer (score 1):

[Stefan Vigerske](https://github.com/svigerske) was kind enough to answer [my question](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/597#issue-1337941015) on the [Ipopt github](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt).

With [minimal changes](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/597#issuecomment-1214193598) one can basically reduce `Ipopt` to a feasibility problem solver.

Comment: Could you explain those changes so the answer is helpful to a wider audience?

Comment: Basically one does not ask for the objective function (gradient) any longer, but keeps it at initial values. One has then to ensure that the objective gradient is identically zero, while the objective can be kept open.